# Xubuntu 13.10 - ATI driver (beta) - Xorg uses 100% CPU

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, xubuntu

Using Xubuntu 13.10, X.Org X Server 1.14.5 and the lastest ATI drivers for my dual R9 270 setup. After some time (a few hours) Xorg starts to use 100% of one core (quad core intel CPU), the system becomes unstable and then stops.

Does anyone know of any patches or a fix for this situation?

I've found [this](http://4x.reddit.com/r/litecoinmining/comments/1s8e0h/cgminer_high_cpu_usage_in_linux/) on reddit:

> This is because of an interrupt storm. This has been a problem with
>   AMD drivers for over a year, and they have still not fixed it. The
>   only fix if you experience this seems to go back to the 12.8 drivers,
>   which is not humanely possible on Linux distros that ship a
>   semi-recent version of all the Xorg software. (It's possible, but not
>   worth it at all.) I had the same problem with later drivers on windows
>   and Linux.
>
> One last fix you can try is setting the affinity of the irq daemon to
>   one core/thread, and limit bfg/cgminer to that core/thread too.

I don't know what how to achieve the last suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) command:

```
taskset 0x00000001 command
```